# illegalArgument exception while using collection SET

Tags: jpa

I am using JPA to persist data.

I have several embedded structures and I have also created entities to suffice the one to many join condition.

while using the following method and after executing the create method in ejb explorer i am getting an illegalArgument exception.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "ZWF_FK_REQA", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_REQ", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_APPR", referencedColumnName = "ID", unique = true) })
    private Set<ApproverData> ApproverData;
```

getter setter method follows.

But while i just replace
*private Set ApproverData*

with

*private List ApproverData*

I don't get any error and data gets persisted.

Is there any special way to use SET while using one to many relation in JPA?

Here's my approver entity code...i have removed the getter setter to save space

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TMP_SM_APPR")
public class ApproverData {
@TableGenerator(name = "TableGenAppr", table = "TMP_GENEXT_IDGEN", pkColumnName = "GEN_NAME", valueColumnName = "GEN_VAL", pkColumnValue = "sm_appr", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "TableGenAppr")
    @Id

    private String id;


    private String appName;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Timestamp Datedec;
```

My jpa class used for persistence is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TMP_SM")
@SecondaryTables( { @SecondaryTable(name = "TMP_REQD", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ID")) })

@NamedQueries( {
        @NamedQuery(name = "Persist.getAll", query = "SELECT po FROM PersistJpa po ORDER BY po.embData.createdAt DESC"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Persist.getItemsCreatedBy", query = "SELECT po FROM PersistJpa po WHERE po.embData.createdBy = :createdBy ORDER BY po.embData.createdAt DESC") })

public class PersistJpa {

    @TableGenerator(name = "SmTableGen", table = "TMP_GENEXT_IDGEN", pkColumnName = "GEN_NAME", valueColumnName = "GEN_VAL", pkColumnValue = "sm", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "SmTableGen")
    @Id
    private String id;


    private String status;



    @Embedded
    private EmbData embData;

    @Embedded
    private EmbReqData embReqData;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "TMP_SM_FK", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_REQ", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_APPR", referencedColumnName = "ID", unique = true) })
    private Set<ApproverData> ApproverData;
```

My bean for persisting using create()

```
@Stateless
public class SmBean implements SmBeanLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(name = "SM")
    EntityManager em;

    public SmBean() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
 // CREATE OPERATION
    public String createItem(PersistJpa item) {
        for (ApproverData data : item.getApproverData()) {
            data.setId(null);
        }
        em.persist(item);
        return item.getId()
}
```

Error that I am getting when using SET instead of List in the method
private Set ApproverData;

is:

```
Error building method parameters. 
[EXCEPTION] 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
at com.sap.ejbexplorer.business.invocation.impl.Query.buildComplexObject(Query.java:213) 
at com.sap.ejbexplorer.business.invocation.impl.Query.buildInvokationArguments(Query.java:136) 
at com.sap.ejbexplorer.business.invocation.impl.Query.execute(Query.java:76) 
at com.sap.ejbexplorer.wdgui.ExplorerView.onActionExecuteQuery(ExplorerView.java:998) 
at com.sap.ejbexplorer.wdgui.wdp.InternalExplorerView.wdInvokeEventHandler(InternalExplorerView.java:543) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.progmodel.generation.DelegatingView.invokeEventHandler(DelegatingView.java:142) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.progmodel.controller.Action.fire(Action.java:75) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.phases.ProcessingEventPhase.doHandleActionEvent(ProcessingEventPhase.java:159) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.phases.ProcessingEventPhase.execute(ProcessingEventPhase.java:94) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.window.WindowPhaseModel.processRequestPartly(WindowPhaseModel.java:162) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.window.WindowPhaseModel.doProcessRequest(WindowPhaseModel.java:110) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.window.WindowPhaseModel.processRequest(WindowPhaseModel.java:97) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.window.WebDynproWindow.processRequest(WebDynproWindow.java:515) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.cal.AbstractClient.executeTasks(AbstractClient.java:58) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.cal.ClientApplication.doExecute(ClientApplication.java:1671) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.cal.ClientApplication.doProcessing(ClientApplication.java:1485) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.session.ApplicationSession.doApplicationProcessingStandalone(ApplicationSession.java:908) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.session.ApplicationSession.doApplicationProcessing(ApplicationSession.java:880) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.session.ApplicationSession.doProcessing(ApplicationSession.java:357) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.session.RequestManager.doProcessing(RequestManager.java:326) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.serverimpl.core.AbstractDispatcherServlet.doContent(AbstractDispatcherServlet.java:87) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.serverimpl.wdc.DispatcherServlet.doContent(DispatcherServlet.java:101) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.serverimpl.core.AbstractDispatcherServlet.doPost(AbstractDispatcherServlet.java:62) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) 
at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.Invokable.invoke(Invokable.java:152) 
at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.Invokable.invoke(Invokable.java:38) 
at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.HttpHandlerImpl.runServlet(HttpHandlerImpl.java:466) 
at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.HttpHandlerImpl.handleRequest(HttpHandlerImpl.java:210) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.RequestAnalizer.startServlet(RequestAnalizer.java:441) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.RequestAnalizer.startServlet(RequestAnalizer.java:430) 
at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.filters.DSRWebContainerFilter.process(DSRWebContainerFilter.java:38) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78) 
at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.filters.ServletSelector.process(ServletSelector.java:81) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78) 
at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.filters.ApplicationSelector.process(ApplicationSelector.java:278) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.WebContainerInvoker.process(WebContainerInvoker.java:81) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.HostFilter.process(HostFilter.java:9) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.ResponseLogWriter.process(ResponseLogWriter.java:60) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.HostFilter.process(HostFilter.java:9) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.DefineHostFilter.process(DefineHostFilter.java:27) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.MonitoringFilter.process(MonitoringFilter.java:29) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.SessionSizeFilter.process(SessionSizeFilter.java:26) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.MemoryStatisticFilter.process(MemoryStatisticFilter.java:57) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.DSRHttpFilter.process(DSRHttpFilter.java:43) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.Processor.chainedRequest(Processor.java:468) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.Processor$FCAProcessorThread.process(Processor.java:262) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.rcm.RequestProcessorThread.run(RequestProcessorThread.java:56) 
at com.sap.engine.core.thread.execution.Executable.run(Executable.java:122) 
at com.sap.engine.core.thread.execution.Executable.run(Executable.java:101) 
at com.sap.engine.core.thread.execution.CentralExecutor$SingleThread.run(CentralExecutor.java:328)
```

Check this in relevence to the create method that I am getting along with the above trace:

```
Error invoking method "createItem(PersistJpa)". 
[EXCEPTION] 
com.sap.ejbexplorer.business.EJBExplorerBusinessException: Error building method parameters. 
at com.sap.ejbexplorer.business.invocation.impl.Query.buildInvokationArguments(Query.java:153) 
at com.sap.ejbexplorer.business.invocation.impl.Query.execute(Query.java:76) 
at com.sap.ejbexplorer.wdgui.ExplorerView.onActionExecuteQuery(ExplorerView.java:998) 
at com.sap.ejbexplorer.wdgui.wdp.InternalExplorerView.wdInvokeEventHandler(InternalExplorerView.java:543) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.progmodel.generation.DelegatingView.invokeEventHandler(DelegatingView.java:142) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.progmodel.controller.Action.fire(Action.java:75) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.phases.ProcessingEventPhase.doHandleActionEvent(ProcessingEventPhase.java:159) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.phases.ProcessingEventPhase.execute(ProcessingEventPhase.java:94) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.window.WindowPhaseModel.processRequestPartly(WindowPhaseModel.java:162) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.window.WindowPhaseModel.doProcessRequest(WindowPhaseModel.java:110) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.window.WindowPhaseModel.processRequest(WindowPhaseModel.java:97) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.window.WebDynproWindow.processRequest(WebDynproWindow.java:515) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.cal.AbstractClient.executeTasks(AbstractClient.java:58) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.cal.ClientApplication.doExecute(ClientApplication.java:1671) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.cal.ClientApplication.doProcessing(ClientApplication.java:1485) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.session.ApplicationSession.doApplicationProcessingStandalone(ApplicationSession.java:908) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.session.ApplicationSession.doApplicationProcessing(ApplicationSession.java:880) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.session.ApplicationSession.doProcessing(ApplicationSession.java:357) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.clientserver.session.RequestManager.doProcessing(RequestManager.java:326) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.serverimpl.core.AbstractDispatcherServlet.doContent(AbstractDispatcherServlet.java:87) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.serverimpl.wdc.DispatcherServlet.doContent(DispatcherServlet.java:101) 
at com.sap.tc.webdynpro.serverimpl.core.AbstractDispatcherServlet.doPost(AbstractDispatcherServlet.java:62) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) 
at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.Invokable.invoke(Invokable.java:152) 
at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.Invokable.invoke(Invokable.java:38) 
at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.HttpHandlerImpl.runServlet(HttpHandlerImpl.java:466) 
at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.HttpHandlerImpl.handleRequest(HttpHandlerImpl.java:210) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.RequestAnalizer.startServlet(RequestAnalizer.java:441) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.RequestAnalizer.startServlet(RequestAnalizer.java:430) 
at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.filters.DSRWebContainerFilter.process(DSRWebContainerFilter.java:38) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78) 
at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.filters.ServletSelector.process(ServletSelector.java:81) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78) 
at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.filters.ApplicationSelector.process(ApplicationSelector.java:278) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.WebContainerInvoker.process(WebContainerInvoker.java:81) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.HostFilter.process(HostFilter.java:9) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.ResponseLogWriter.process(ResponseLogWriter.java:60) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.HostFilter.process(HostFilter.java:9) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.DefineHostFilter.process(DefineHostFilter.java:27) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.MonitoringFilter.process(MonitoringFilter.java:29) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.SessionSizeFilter.process(SessionSizeFilter.java:26) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.MemoryStatisticFilter.process(MemoryStatisticFilter.java:57) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.DSRHttpFilter.process(DSRHttpFilter.java:43) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.Processor.chainedRequest(Processor.java:468) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.Processor$FCAProcessorThread.process(Processor.java:262) 
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.rcm.RequestProcessorThread.run(RequestProcessorThread.java:56) 
at com.sap.engine.core.thread.execution.Executable.run(Executable.java:122) 
at com.sap.engine.core.thread.execution.Executable.run(Executable.java:101) 
at com.sap.engine.core.thread.execution.CentralExecutor$SingleThread.run(CentralExecutor.java:328) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
at com.sap.ejbexplorer.business.invocation.impl.Query.buildComplexObject(Query.java:213) 
at com.sap.ejbexplorer.business.invocation.impl.Query.buildInvokationArguments(Query.java:136) 
... 62 more
```

I don't get any error and data is persisted if i change the return type of the method ApproverData from Set to List.

Comment: Kindly post your CODE that you use for persisting, that you say causes the problem (you didn't post any METHOD, just a fields declaration). JPA imposes nothing on use of a Set type. If posting some exception, post it plus the STACK TRACE

Comment: and what relevance does the stack trace have to do with your persistence code? I don't see it mentioned in the stack trace ...